# Cleaner way to define multiple variables for is_page_template()

Tags: page-template, variables, customization

I need to so some stuff only when specific templates (homepages) are used, I couldn't think of any better solution than this since is_page_template() do not handle arrays:

```
        $home_1 = is_page_template('home-1.php');
        $home_2 = is_page_template('home-2.php');
        $home_3 = is_page_template('home-3.php');
        $home_4 = is_page_template('home-4.php');
        $home_5 = is_page_template('home-5.php');
        $home_6 = is_page_template('home-6.php');

        if ( $home_1 || $home_2 || $home_3 || $home_4 || $home_5 || $home_6  ) {
             //Do stuff
        }
```

Since I need this for several parts, I was wondering if there is any cleaner way to do this not to repeat the same code throughout template files? Maybe inside a function in functions.php? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [Alternative](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template#Alternative)

```
<?php 
  // in the loop:
  $template = get_page_template_slug( get_the_ID() );
  if (in_array($template,array('home1','home2')) ) ){
     // Yep, Do your stuff
  }

  // anywhere:
  $template = get_page_template_slug( $some_post_ID );
  if (in_array($template,array('home1','home2')) ) ){
     // Yep, Do your stuff
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**is_page_template()** does support arrays! Here's an example:

```
if ( is_page_template( array(
    'home-1.php',
    'home-2.php',
    'home-3.php',
    'home-4.php',
    'home-5.php',
    'home-6.php'
) ) )  
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/